# Jquery show/hide resetting when page reloads

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jquery, but I'm trying to use it to create a multi-step tabbed form.

One one of the pages, I have radio buttons that will show several fields depending on the choice that's selected.

The problem I find is that if the user refreshes the page after selecting a radio button, the page reloads and hides all the divs, but it remembers the selected radio button choice.

Is there a way to initially hide the divs without explicitly telling it to happen after a page loads? Perhaps some (easy) way of having jquery remember what div is hidden and which is shown?

Thanks!

```
<label for="paymentmethod">Payment Method</label>
<input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" id="paymentmethod" value="creditcard">Visa/Mastercard
<input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" id="paymentmethod" value="cheque">Cheque

<div id="divcredit">
 Stuff
</div>

<div id="divcheque">
 Stuff
</div>
```

Here's the jquery code I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//...stuff

$("#divcredit").hide();
$("#divcheque").hide();

$("input[name='paymentmethod']").change(function() {
    if( $("input[name='paymentmethod']:checked").val() == "cheque")
    {
        $("#divcredit").hide();
        $("#divcheque").show();
    }
    else if($("input[name='paymentmethod']:checked").val()== "creditcard")
    {
        $("#divcredit").show();
        $("#divcheque").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: What browser are you using? I don't think that keeping form data on refresh (unless you've programmed it specifically) is something that happens with all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var setPaymentDivs = function() {
  var selected = $('input[name="paymentmethod"]:checked').val();
  $('div.payment').hide();
  $('#div' + selected).show();
};

$(function() {
  setPaymentDivs();
  $('input[name="paymentmethod"]').change(setPaymentDivs);
});
```

and add `class="payment"` to the divs. This abuses the fact that the back button and refresh remember the form values.

Another way is to encode the current state somewhere - in a cookie, in a URL hash... and then extract it on load and set all the values accordingly. Advantage is that it works even if you shut down the browser, and in the case of URL hashes, even if you paste the URL to your friend's browser. (Well, maybe not for payment system :D but you know what I mean)

Answer (score 2):

Cookies are your friends.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

--or, with a jQuery plugin--

http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie

Or, localStorage is your friend!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//...stuff
if (localStorage['payment']) {
    if (localStorage['payment'] === 'credit')
        $("#divcheque").hide();
    else
        $("#divcredit").hide();
}
else {
    $("#divcheque").hide();
    $("#divcredit").hide();
}    

$("input[name='paymentmethod']").change(function() {
    if( $("input[name='paymentmethod']:checked").val() == "cheque")
    {
        $("#divcredit").hide();
        $("#divcheque").show();
        localStorage['payment'] = 'cheque';
    }
    else if($("input[name='paymentmethod']:checked").val()== "creditcard")
    {
        $("#divcredit").show();
        $("#divcheque").hide();
        localStorage['payment'] = 'credit';
    }
});
```

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/storage.html

For cross-browser compatibility, use cookies. But in both ways, it would work even after your users have left for some time; something you might or might not want.

Answer (score 1):

try after you configure the change event.

```
if( $("input[name='paymentmethod']:checked").length > 0){
   $("input[name='paymentmethod']").change();
}
```

This means that after you load the page, check if there is an option selected and fire the event to get the behavior you want

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is to use (one of) the [jQuery history plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history)(s). This will allow the browser to go back to showing the div you want based on the hash.

However, if you're relying on the page keeping checked/unchecked values on refresh, this will only work properly if you add code for it. Ie. Not all browsers keep the form values on page refresh unless the page has been explicitly set up to do so. That most likely means posting the data via ajax, storing the info in a session and having the page take that info into account when it outputs.

Comment: I don't really care one way or another if it is kept. The problem is, when it IS kept,  the way I have the code right now has the radio button kept but the div is hidden again, and since I'm using the onChange event, the radio button needs to change before the show/hide code function gets run again. 

Is there an alternative other than manually storing the history?

Comment: @Jordan: Well, there's all the other answers posted here, but on the other hand you *could* just clear the form elements when the page loads. That way you'll know the user is always starting fresh. Actually, I'm not sure that the load or dom ready events are even called when you refresh the page which would negate all of these answers. I guess the only way to do it for sure would be to have a script tag at the bottom of the page with the reset/checking code in it.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly modifying your jquery by extracting out a method:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //...stuff

    ShowHidePanels();

    $("input[name='paymentmethod']").change(function() {
        ShowHidePanels();
    });

    function ShowHidePanels(){
        if( $("input[name='paymentmethod']:checked").val() == "cheque")
        {
            $("#divcredit").hide();
            $("#divcheque").show();
        }
        else if($("input[name='paymentmethod']:checked").val()== "creditcard")
        {
            $("#divcredit").show();
            $("#divcheque").hide();
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Wow I'm slow, anyway here is my solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/FerMU/

Also you have some confusion with labels and IDs on the checkboxes.