# Maintain hidden div selection from array after page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, refresh, hidden

I have created an array of div ids, so that the user of the page can toggle between selecting just one of the divs to be shown or all of them. My script is shown below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function switchdivs(theid){
var thearray= new Array("div1", "div2", "div3");
for(i=0; i<thearray.length; i++){
  if(thearray[i] == theid || theid == "all"){
        document.getElementById(thearray[i]).style.display="block";

  }else{
document.getElementById(thearray[i]).style.display="none";
  }
}
}
</script>
```

I wish to keep the selection of the user after page refresh. I have read some examples of this, such as [Jquery show/hide resetting when page reloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642564/jquery-show-hide-resetting-when-page-reloads) which have helped my understanding but I still can't get it to work with my array. Do I need to set up the rules for each individual id, or is there a more elegant solution using the array? I have tried something like this, but as you can probably tell from my poor script I'm very new to javascript and am pretty lost:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

if (sessionStorage['divselection']) {
if (sessionStorage['divselection'] === 'theid')
    $("#theid").show();
else
    $("#thearray[i]").hide();
}  

$("input[name='theid']").change(function() {
if( $("input[name='thearray[i]']:checked").val() == "theid")
{
    $("#thearray[i]").hide();
    $("#theid").show();
    sessionStorage['divselection'] = 'theid';
}
});
```

Thank you for any help in pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of CSS class names is that you can apply them to **groups** of elements. So instead of tracking individual IDs, use classes.

Also, instead of hiding and showing elements, use class names once again, but associate the class name with an actual style. Such as:

```
.hideMe {
    display:none
}
```

...then you can add/remove the class name which does all the hide/show for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This wouldn't solve the problem of keeping the selection after a page refresh though, would it? My script for hiding/showing works fine, I just wanted to be able to keep the selection after a refresh eg using cookies or session storage.

Comment: You asked "Do I need to set up the rules for each individual id, or is there a more elegant solution using the array?" -- this answers that. You may want to consider a "url hash" technique to solve keeping state.