# JQuery - how to remember show/hide elements when navigating back from another page of a form

Tags: jquery, show-hide, onload

I am new to JQuery and am stumped with how to get JQuery to remember the show/hide status of an element on a form when the user navigates away from the current page then returns. I.e. when the they have made a selection from a drop-down question, which reveals a second question (a text box), they've typed in an answer then clicked the built in  button to go to the next page, then clicked the  button to return.

With the code below the question IPQ_OTHRES is hidden onload of the current page, and therefore obviously when navigating back from the next page it is hidden again despite the selection made in the previous drop-down question. IPQ_OTHRES is set to show when the user chooses 'N' from the dropdown menu question IPQ_THREE:

```
// Controls the show/hide of Other Resident Country based on answer to IPQ_THREE

        $('#IPQ_OTHRES').hide().removeClass('mandatoryInput');
        $('#IPQ_OTHRES_DIV').hide();

        $('#IPQ_THREE').change(function(){
            var IPQ_THREEVal = $('select[name=IPQ_THREE] option:selected').val();

                if (IPQ_THREEVal == "N"){
                        $('#IPQ_OTHRES_DIV').show()
                        $('#IPQ_OTHRES').show().addClass('mandatoryInput');
                    } else if (IPQ_THREEVal == "Y"){
                        $('#IPQ_OTHRES_DIV').hide()
                        $('#IPQ_OTHRES').hide().removeClass('mandatoryInput');
                    } else {
                        $('#IPQ_OTHRES_DIV').hide()
                        $('#IPQ_OTHRES').hide().removeClass('mandatoryInput');
                }
            });
```

I have been reading about JQuery cookie and localStorage as possible solutions. The closest I've come to an answer so far is from this question post: [Jquery show/hide resetting when page reloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642564/jquery-show-hide-resetting-when-page-reloads/5642642#5642642)

but that uses show/hide based on radio buttons rather than a drop down. I've been told my first two lines need their own 'if..else' statement around them to pick up the value of IPQ_THREE onload and show/hide accordingly. I've tried to do this and am stuck. Can anyone help? I really need to sort this so I can apply it to other elements.

Many thanks,

Mark.

Comment: I think you should use server side script to remember those.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices here

1. Use a server side technology like database to remember the previous status
2. Use a client side technology

In client side there are two ways you can do it

[Cookie](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2109/rfc2109)
Use cookie to store the value(a state value like hide/show a particular element), since you are using jQuery you can use a cookie library like [this one](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.cookie)

[webstorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/PR-webstorage-20130409/)
If you are supporting only modern browsers(html5), then you can think about [webstorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/PR-webstorage-20130409/) like [session storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/PR-webstorage-20130409/#dom-sessionstorage)